# targeting one word in the response of an input command python

Tags: python

I have been trying to make an artificial intelligence on python. What I have been trying to do is make input command responses target one word. So for example, if the user types in "whats your name" it will have the same response as "name" by targeting the word "name". how can I do this?

Comment: Question is ambiguous. please improve it.

Answer (score 0):

What you're looking for is a library for handling [Parts of Speech](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Part_of_speech). Luckily it's pretty well trodden ground, and there are libraries for lots of different languages - including Python. Have a look at [Stanford's Natural Language Toolkit](http://textminingonline.com/dive-into-nltk-part-v-using-stanford-text-analysis-tools-in-python) (NLTK). Here's an example from the linked article:

```
>>> from nltk.tag.stanford import POSTagger
>>> english_postagger = POSTagger(‘models/english-bidirectional-distsim.tagger’, ‘stanford-postagger.jar’)
>>> english_postagger.tag(‘this is stanford postagger in nltk for python users’.split())
[(u’this’, u’DT’),
(u’is’, u’VBZ’),
(u’stanford’, u’JJ’),
(u’postagger’, u’NN’),
(u’in’, u’IN’),
(u’nltk’, u’NN’),
(u’for’, u’IN’),
(u’python’, u’NN’),
(u’users’, u’NNS’)]
```

The `NN`, `VBZ`, etc. you  can see are [speech tags](https://cs.nyu.edu/grishman/jet/guide/PennPOS.html). It looks like you're looking for nouns (`NN`).